# Ambiguous Overload For Operator

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I am working on class CBigInt. CBigInt class is class of in integers with infinite length. It looks like this :

```
class CBigInt{
  public:
    string number;
    int sign;
    CBigInt()
    CBigInt(const int a);
    CBigInt(const string a);
    CBigInt& operator = (const string rhs);
    CBigInt& operator=(const CBigInt& rhs);
    CBigInt& operator=(int rhs );
    CBigInt& operator+=(const CBigInt& rhs);
    CBigInt operator+(const CBigInt& rhs);
    CBigInt& operator+=(const string rhs);
    CBigInt operator+(const string rhs);
    CBigInt& operator *=(const CBigInt& rhs);
    CBigInt operator*(const CBigInt& rhs);
    CBigInt& operator*=(const string rhs);
    CBigInt operator*(const string rhs);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& off, const CBigInt& big);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in,  CBigInt& big );
}
```

All operators are defined, and works find at all examples i could think of, except this one:

```
CBigInt       a, b;
a *= 0;
```

Where compilator cant decide which of two funcions to use:

```
CBigInt& operator *=(const CBigInt& rhs);
or
CBigInt& operator *=(const string rhs);
```

I read few questions which were very similar but it didnt help much.

error:

```
/home/michal/Desktop/prog/big/main.cpp||In function ‘int main()’:|
/home/michal/Desktop/prog/big/main.cpp|345|error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator*=’ in ‘a *= 0’|
/home/michal/Desktop/prog/big/main.cpp|345|note: candidates are:|
/home/michal/Desktop/prog/big/main.cpp|198|note: CBigInt& CBigInt::operator*=(const CBigInt&)|
/home/michal/Desktop/prog/big/main.cpp|247|note: CBigInt& CBigInt::operator*=(std::string)|
||=== Build finished: 4 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

Comment: Don't use operator overloading, especially, don't overuse it, and especially don't use it in combination with syntactic overloading. Just my two cents ;)

Comment: @DanielDaranas, I'd say it makes classes act much more natural, but in this case, keep it limited to `CBigInt *= CBigInt` or maybe other integral types if doing `CBigInt(someInt)` is too much. `CBigInt *= std::string` seems very awkward.

Comment: well its school assignment ... its for learning about overloading

Comment: @DanielDaranas: Don't know what terrible language you came from, but here in the C++ world, we use overloading like this all the time.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/jutYr9ma I dont know ... = now seems to work completly wrong .. am I missing something ?

Comment: @DeadMG I've been programming in C++ professionally for 13 years now. I have fixed several bugs which were related to the overuse of syntactic overloading and operator overloading. I have no problem with operator overloading when it is _not_ syntactically overloaded, but when it is, I consider it unnecessarily ambiguous. I don't come from any terrible language, just from the OO software construction theory by Bertrand Meyer. See more from him on overloading in [this article](http://se.inf.ethz.ch/~meyer/publications/publications/joop/overloading.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

Simply remove this operator

```
CBigInt operator*(const string rhs);
```

It is enough to have operator

```
CBigInt operator*(const CBigInt& rhs);
```

because the class has two conversion constructors

```
CBigInt(const int a);
CBigInt(const string a);
```

So instead of the set of operators

```
CBigInt& operator = (const string rhs);
CBigInt& operator=(const CBigInt& rhs);
CBigInt& operator=(int rhs );
CBigInt& operator+=(const CBigInt& rhs);
CBigInt operator+(const CBigInt& rhs);
CBigInt& operator+=(const string rhs);
CBigInt operator+(const string rhs);
CBigInt& operator *=(const CBigInt& rhs);
CBigInt operator*(const CBigInt& rhs);
CBigInt& operator*=(const string rhs);
CBigInt operator*(const string rhs);
```

you could write

```
CBigInt& operator=(const CBigInt& rhs);
CBigInt& operator+=(const CBigInt& rhs);
CBigInt operator+(const CBigInt& rhs);
CBigInt& operator *=(const CBigInt& rhs);
CBigInt operator*(const CBigInt& rhs);
```

Also change the constructors from

```
CBigInt(const int a);
CBigInt(const string a);
```

to

```
CBigInt( int a);
CBigInt(const string &a);
```

Take into account that the code contains typos. You missed semicolons after

```
   CBigInt()
```

and

the closing brace of the class definition.

For example this code is compiled successfully

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class CBigInt{
  public:
    std::string number;
    int sign;
    CBigInt() {}
    CBigInt(const int a) {}
    CBigInt(const std::string &a) {}
    CBigInt& operator=(const CBigInt& rhs) { return *this; }
    CBigInt& operator+=(const CBigInt& rhs);
    CBigInt operator+(const CBigInt& rhs);
    CBigInt& operator *=(const CBigInt& rhs) { return *this; }
    CBigInt operator*(const CBigInt& rhs);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& off, const CBigInt& big);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in,  CBigInt& big );
};

int main() 
{
    CBigInt i1, i2, i3;

    i1 = i2 *= i3;

    i1 *= 0;

    i1 *= std::string( "Hello" );

    return 0;
}
```

If you need to work with string literals then you can for example add overloaded operator

```
    CBigInt& operator *=(const char *rhs) { return *this; }
```

Comment: when i edit my code this way. It gives   /home/michal/Desktop/prog/big/main.cpp||In function ‘int main()’:|
/home/michal/Desktop/prog/big/main.cpp|311|error: no match for ‘operator+=’ in ‘a += 20’|
/home/michal/Desktop/prog/big/main.cpp|311|note: candidate is:|
/home/michal/Desktop/prog/big/main.cpp|53|note: CBigInt& CBigInt::operator+=(const CBigInt&)|
/home/michal/Desktop/prog/big/main.cpp|53|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const CBigInt&’|

Comment: @user3512285, There's no reason for that error with those constructors.

Comment: Your non-mutating binary operators are not correctly labelled `const`. Also, you could seriously consider whether or not separate ralue reference overloads are worth it.

Comment: @DeadMG how should i fix it then. i dont understand it much.

Comment: I need   ' i1 *= "1534"; ' to work. thats why i had those string operators.

Comment: @user3512285 Then overload the operator for parameter of type const char *

Comment: Instead of saying `i1 *= std::string("Hello");`, I would prefer `i1 *= CBigInt("Hello");` (and probably an actual number as well ;))

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow I overloaded const char *  still not working. (operator =  works fine =*, *, +, +=  not so much)

Comment: CBigInt& operator *=(const char *rhs) { return *this; } also not working : no match for ‘operator+=’ in ‘a += "-99999999999999999999"’|

Comment: @user3512285 Define all operators you need. I showed compiled code. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix is to do `a *= CBigInt(0);`.

Comment: i am writing this class for school assignment. And cant influence testing data.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no `operator*=` function that has the type `int` as argument type, the compiler has to decide which other ones can be used. It finds that an `int` can be converted to both a `CBigInt` as well as a `string`. The compiler is not able to resolve that ambiguity. Hence the error. You can resolve that by being explicit. I think you want to use

```
a *= CBigInt(0);
```

Comment: error: only declarations of constructors can be ‘explicit’|

Comment: @user3512285, That has nothing to do with this answer. All it says is to be explicit, meaning `CBigInt(0)` instead of `0`.

Comment: my bad. But i cant be explicit anyway, because testing data are not mine.

Comment: @user3512285, Does the assignment enforce that exact `int` conversion constructor and both `operator*=`s exactly as shown? Then it's not possible to work around and whoever's in charge of your assignment would be much more help.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to mark your conversion operators explicit:

```
explicit CBigInt(const std::string &a) {}
```

This will prevent the conversion from being considered for overload resolution of operator *=.

If you define both a conversion operator and overloads that could potentially use that conversion operator, you're going to have a bad time. In general, implicit conversions should be avoided unless they are both very necessary and extremely straightforward.

Use the built-in type system as a guide. If the C++ standard would require an explicit cast between equivalent types (which it would, between an int and a char*), then your conversion operator shouldn't be implicit.